# Swift protocol extension method is called instead of method implemented in subclass

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols, dynamic-dispatch

I've encountered a problem that is explained in the code below (Swift 3.1):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func methodA()
    func methodB()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func methodA() {
        print("Default methodA")
    }

    func methodB() {
        methodA()
    }
}

// Test 1
class BaseClass: MyProtocol {

}

class SubClass: BaseClass {
    func methodA() {
        print("SubClass methodA")
    }
}


let object1 = SubClass()
object1.methodB()
//

// Test 2
class JustClass: MyProtocol {
    func methodA() {
        print("JustClass methodA")
    }
}

let object2 = JustClass()
object2.methodB()
//
// Output
// Default methodA
// JustClass methodA
```

So I would expect that *"SubClass methodA"* text should be printed after `object1.methodB()` call. But for some reason default implementation of `methodA()` from protocol extension is called. However `object2.methodB()`call works as expected.

Is it another Swift bug in protocol method dispatching or am I missing something and the code works correctly?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This is just how protocols currently dispatch methods.

A protocol witness table (see [this WWDC talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9By9KLs51Dc) for more info) is used in order to dynamically dispatch to implementations of protocol requirements upon being called on a protocol-typed instance. All it is, is really just a listing of the function implementations to call for each requirement of the protocol for a given conforming type.

Each type that states its conformance to a protocol gets its own protocol witness table. You'll note that I said "states its conformance", and not just "conforms to". `BaseClass` gets its own protocol witness table for conformance to `MyProtocol`. However `SubClass` does *not* get its own table for conformance to `MyProtocol` – instead, it simply relies on `BaseClass`'s. If you moved the
 `: MyProtocol` down to the definition of `SubClass`, it would get to have its own PWT.

So all we have to think about here is what the PWT for `BaseClass` looks like. Well, it doesn't provide an implementation for either of the protocol requirements `methodA()` or `methodB()` – so it relies on the implementations in the protocol extension. What this means is that the PWT for `BaseClass` conforming to `MyProtocol` just contains mappings to the extension methods.

So, when the extension `methodB()` method is called, and makes the call out to `methodA()`, it dynamically dispatches that call through the PWT (as it's being called on a protocol-typed instance; namely `self`). So when this happens with a `SubClass` instance, we're going through `BaseClass`'s PWT. So we end up calling the extension implementation of `methodA()`, regardless of the fact that `SubClass` provides an implementation of it.

Now let's consider the PWT of `JustClass`. It provides an implementation of `methodA()`, therefore its PWT for conformance to `MyProtocol` has *that* implementation as the mapping for `methodA()`, as well as the extension implementation for `methodB()`. So when `methodA()` is dynamically dispatched via its PWT, we end up in *its* implementation.

As I say [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42286148/2976878), this behaviour of subclasses not getting their own PWTs for protocols that their superclass(es) conform to is indeed somewhat surprising, and has been [filed as a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1729). The reasoning behind it, as Swift team member Jordan Rose says in the comments of the bug report, is

> [...] The subclass does not get to provide new members to satisfy the conformance. This is important because a protocol can be added to a base class in one module and a subclass created in another module.

Therefore if this was the behaviour, already-compiled subclasses would lack any PWTs from superclass conformances that were added after the fact in another module, which would be problematic.

---

As others have already said, one solution in this case is to have `BaseClass` provide its own implementation of `methodA()`. This method will now be in `BaseClass`'s PWT, rather than the extension method.

Although of course, because we're dealing with *classes* here, it won't just be `BaseClass`'s implementation of the method that's listed – instead it will be a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) that then dynamically dispatches through the class' vtable (the mechanism by which classes achieve polymorphism). Therefore for a `SubClass` instance, we'll wind up calling its override of `methodA()`.

Comment: long story short, is it correct to say, the PWT gets updated when you either **directly** *conform* or *extend* a protocol requirement? Which in this case is: `extension MyProtocol {
    func methodA() {
        print("Default methodA");
    }

    func methodB() {
        methodA();
    }
}

class BaseClass: MyProtocol {

}`. Having that said, the PWT won't re-map once you subclass, rather *per* each rewrite(`class SubClass : BaseClass{
    func methodA() {
        print("subClass methodA")
    }
}`

Comment: I said rewrite because it seems it's neither the actual *conformance* nor an _override_ of a method requirement, it will _update_ that only. I'm curious to know what's the correct jargon for it

Comment: @Honey The PWT gets evaluated at the site at which protocol conformance is stated, and it's done at compile-time, so I'm not really sure either "update" or "rewrite" is quite correct. Subclassing doesn't have any effect on the base class' PWT, but changes in dispatch may be noticed if say `BaseClass` provides its own implementation of `methodA`, and then `SubClass` comes along and overrides that implementation (because now with a protocol-typed `SubClass` instance, we're dispatching first to the PWT, and then to the class vtable). The PWT remains the same tho, only `SubClass`'s vtable changes.

Comment: 1) so you're saying we have a PWT and class vTable, which are somewhat similar and every method gets dispatched based on the combined result of the two? 2) specifically about methodA from the first test of the OP, the PWT is changed, but eventually the class vtable is changed and so it points to where the subclass's vtable points to. However for methodB, its subclass hasn't made any changes and it just points to where the PWT says it should point to? 3. In general: even though subclassing can affect dispatch, it doesn't PWT, it can only affect class vtable; only conformance affects PWT. Right?

Comment: @Honey 1) Yes, if you're dealing with a protocol-typed instance of a class; the dispatch of the protocol requirements will be determined by the PWT + vtable. 2) I'm not quite sure what you mean by "PWT is changed"; changed from what to what? The subclass doesn't have any influence on the PWT, no; that's purely determined by `BaseClass`'s conformance to the protocol (whether it provides its own implementations of the requirements). And yes, I think that then answers #3 :)

Comment: "no; that's purely determined by BaseClass's conformance to the protocol (whether it provides its own implementations of the requirem". You mean the default implementation? It all makes sense now.

Comment: @Honey Yes, if `BaseClass` doesn't provide its own implementation of the protocol requirements, the extension implementations will get listed in its PWT; and thus will be the ones dynamically dispatched to (when called on a protocol-typed instance). Glad it makes sense :)

Comment: It looks like a possible workaround at least in some cases, could be replacing "class hierarchy" with "protocol hierarchy" (with implementations provided in protocol extensions). See https://gist.github.com/grigorye/fa4fce6f0ca63cfb97b3c48448a98239 for the original sample switched to protocols.

Comment: In such a case (see the my comment above), in case of subclass we defer "instantiation" of PWT till the class definition, as it states the conformance itself, while "inheriting" "base" implementations from the base protocol not from the base class.

Comment: Another workaround would be replacing default implementations in protocol with a dummy "Defaults" class that would provide them. It quite limited solution, but might be worth considering. Imho, it makes whole thing more clear/understandable because it enforces "override" for both base-class and sub-class overrides of the default implementation. See https://gist.github.com/grigorye/27e0f6e4f50a7650768ccd1761f6587a

Comment: @GrigoryEntin Both useful workarounds – thanks for mentioning them! Such workarounds do depend on the exact use case though, for example you might not be able to control the base class' conformance to a given protocol or the base class may inherit from another type.

Answer (score 2):

A very short answer that a friend shared with me was:

> Only the class that declares the conformance gets a protocol witness table

Meaning a subclass having that function has no effect on how the protocol witness table is setup.

The protocol witness is a contract only between the protocol, it's extensions, and the concrete class that implements it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose the subclass method A is not polymorphic because you can't put the override keyword on it, since the class doesn't know the method is implemented in an extension of the protocol and thus doesn't let you override it. The extension method is probably stepping on your implementation in runtime, much like 2 exact category methods trump each other with undefined behavior in objective C. You can fix this behavior by adding another layer in your model and implementing the methods in a class rather than the protocol extension, thus getting polymorphic behavior out of them. The downside is that you cannot leave methods unimplemented in this layer, as there is no native support for abstract classes (which is really what you're trying to do with protocol extensions)

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func methodA()
    func methodB()
}

class MyProtocolClass: MyProtocol {
    func methodA() {
        print("Default methodA")
    }

    func methodB() {
        methodA()
    }
}

// Test 1
class BaseClass: MyProtocolClass {

}

class SubClass: BaseClass {
    override func methodA() {
        print("SubClass methodA")
    }
}


let object1 = SubClass()
object1.methodB()
//

// Test 2
class JustClass: MyProtocolClass {
    override func methodA() {
        print("JustClass methodA")
    }
}

let object2 = JustClass()
object2.methodB()
//
// Output
// SubClass methodA
// JustClass methodA
```

Also relevante answer here: [Swift Protocol Extensions overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431753/swift-protocol-extensions-overriding)

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
let object1 = SubClass()
object1.methodB()
```

You invoked methodB from an instance of `SubClass`, but `SubClass` does not have any method named `methodB`. However its super class, `BaseClass` conform to `MyProtocol`, which has a `methodB` methodB.

So, it will invoke the `methodB` from `MyProtocal`. Therefore it will execute the `methodA` in `extesion MyProtocol`.

To reach what you expect, you need implement `methodA` in `BaseClass` and override it in `SubClass`, like the following code

```
class BaseClass: MyProtocol {
    func methodA() {
        print("BaseClass methodA")
    }
}

class SubClass: BaseClass {
    override func methodA() {
        print("SubClass methodA")
    }
}
```

Now, output would become

```
//Output
//SubClass methodA
//JustClass methodA
```

Although the method can reach what you expect, but I'm not sure this kind of code struct is recommended.