# Which dispatch method would be used in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In WWDC [Understanding Swift Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/), it declared when object's type is a protocol: Call a function required by the protocol would use Existential container to dispatch methods.

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
    func testFuncA()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func testFuncA() {
        print("MyProtocol's testFuncA")
    }
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {}

// This use Existential Container, find implementation through PWT.
let object: MyProtocol = MyClass()
object.testFuncA()
```

And here comes my question: When **object** is specified as **MyClass**, how does Swift find the implementation? I have two explanations for the question.

1. Is it the extension's default implementation copied to **MyClass**'s v-table, and method being dispatched through **MyClass**'s v-table?
2. Is it still use Existential container to dispatch methods, and the Existential container's PWT contains extension's default implementation?

```swift
// Use Dynamic Dispatch or Static Dispatch? How?
let object: MyClass = MyClass()
object.testFuncA()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift protocol extension method is called instead of method implemented in subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703205/swift-protocol-extension-method-is-called-instead-of-method-implemented-in-subcl)

Answer (score 13):

In this example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func testFuncA()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func testFuncA() {
        print("MyProtocol's testFuncA")
    }
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {}

let object: MyClass = MyClass()
object.testFuncA()
```

*static dispatch* is used. The concrete type of `object` is known at compile time; it's `MyClass`. Swift can then see that it conforms to `MyProtocol` without providing its own implementation of `testFuncA()`, so it can dispatch straight to the extension method.

So to answer your individual questions:

> 1) Is it the extension's default implementation copied to `MyClass`'s
>   v-table, and method being dispatched through `MyClass`'s v-table?

No – a Swift class v-table only holds methods defined in the body of the class declaration. That is to say:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  func testFuncA()
}

extension MyProtocol {
  // No entry in MyClass' Swift v-table.
  // (but an entry in MyClass' protocol witness table for conformance to MyProtocol)
  func testFuncA() {
    print("MyProtocol's testFuncA")
  }
}

class MyClass : MyProtocol {
  // An entry in MyClass' Swift v-table.
  func foo() {}
}

extension MyClass {
  // No entry in MyClass' Swift v-table (this is why you can't override
  // extension methods without using Obj-C message dispatch).
  func bar() {}
}
```

> 2) Is it still use Existential container to dispatch methods, and the
>   Existential container's PWT contains extension's default
>   implementation?

There are no existential containers in the code:

```
let object: MyClass = MyClass()
object.testFuncA()
```

Existential containers are used for *protocol-typed instances*, such as your first example:

```
let object: MyProtocol = MyClass()
object.testFuncA()
```

The `MyClass` instance is boxed in an existential container with a protocol witness table that maps calls to `testFuncA()` to the extension method (now we're dealing with dynamic dispatch).

---

A nice way to see all of the above in action is by taking a look at the SIL generated by the compiler; which is a fairly high-level intermediate representation of the generated code (but low-level enough to see what kind of dispatch mechanisms are in play).

You can do so by running the following (note it's best to first remove `print` statements from your program, as they inflate the size of the SIL generated *considerably*):

```
swiftc -emit-sil main.swift | xcrun swift-demangle > main.silgen
```

Let's take a look at the SIL for the first example in this answer. Here's the `main` function, which is the entry-point of the program:

```
// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  alloc_global @main.object : main.MyClass       // id: %2
  %3 = global_addr @main.object : main.MyClass : $*MyClass // users: %9, %7

  // function_ref MyClass.__allocating_init()
  %4 = function_ref @main.MyClass.__allocating_init() -> main.MyClass : $@convention(method) (@thick MyClass.Type) -> @owned MyClass // user: %6
  %5 = metatype $@thick MyClass.Type              // user: %6
  %6 = apply %4(%5) : $@convention(method) (@thick MyClass.Type) -> @owned MyClass // user: %7
  store %6 to %3 : $*MyClass                      // id: %7

  // Get a reference to the extension method and call it (static dispatch).
  // function_ref MyProtocol.testFuncA()
  %8 = function_ref @(extension in main):main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> () : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> () // user: %12
  %9 = load %3 : $*MyClass                        // user: %11
  %10 = alloc_stack $MyClass                      // users: %11, %13, %12
  store %9 to %10 : $*MyClass                     // id: %11
  %12 = apply %8<MyClass>(%10) : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> ()
  dealloc_stack %10 : $*MyClass                   // id: %13


  %14 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0         // user: %15
  %15 = struct $Int32 (%14 : $Builtin.Int32)      // user: %16
  return %15 : $Int32                             // id: %16
} // end sil function 'main'
```

The bit that we're interested in here is this line:

```
  %8 = function_ref @(extension in main):main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> () : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> () // user: %12
```

The [`function_ref`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#function_ref) instruction gets a reference to a function *known at compile-time*. You can see that it's getting a reference to the function `@(extension in main):main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> ()`, which is the method in the protocol extension. Thus Swift is using static dispatch.

Let's now take a look at what happens when we make the call like this:

```
let object: MyProtocol = MyClass()
object.testFuncA()
```

The `main` function now looks like this:

```
// main
sil @main : $@convention(c) (Int32, UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>) -> Int32 {
bb0(%0 : $Int32, %1 : $UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>>>):
  alloc_global @main.object : main.MyProtocol  // id: %2
  %3 = global_addr @main.object : main.MyProtocol : $*MyProtocol // users: %9, %4
  // Create an opaque existential container and get its address (%4).
  %4 = init_existential_addr %3 : $*MyProtocol, $MyClass // user: %8
  // function_ref MyClass.__allocating_init()
  %5 = function_ref @main.MyClass.__allocating_init() -> main.MyClass : $@convention(method) (@thick MyClass.Type) -> @owned MyClass // user: %7
  %6 = metatype $@thick MyClass.Type              // user: %7
  %7 = apply %5(%6) : $@convention(method) (@thick MyClass.Type) -> @owned MyClass // user: %8

  // Store the MyClass instance in the existential container.
  store %7 to %4 : $*MyClass                      // id: %8

  // Open the existential container to get a pointer to the MyClass instance.
  %9 = open_existential_addr immutable_access %3 : $*MyProtocol to $*@opened("F199B87A-06BA-11E8-A29C-DCA9047B1400") MyProtocol // users: %11, %11, %10

 // Dynamically lookup the function to call for the testFuncA requirement. 
  %10 = witness_method $@opened("F199B87A-06BA-11E8-A29C-DCA9047B1400") MyProtocol, #MyProtocol.testFuncA!1 : <Self where Self : MyProtocol> (Self) -> () -> (), %9 : $*@opened("F199B87A-06BA-11E8-A29C-DCA9047B1400") MyProtocol : $@convention(witness_method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> () // type-defs: %9; user: %11

  // Call the function we looked-up for the testFuncA requirement.
  %11 = apply %10<@opened("F199B87A-06BA-11E8-A29C-DCA9047B1400") MyProtocol>(%9) : $@convention(witness_method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> () // type-defs: %9


  %12 = integer_literal $Builtin.Int32, 0         // user: %13
  %13 = struct $Int32 (%12 : $Builtin.Int32)      // user: %14
  return %13 : $Int32                             // id: %14
} // end sil function 'main'
```

There are some key differences here.

An (opaque) existential container is created with [`init_existential_addr`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#init-existential-addr), and the `MyClass` instance is stored into it (`store %7 to %4`).

The existential container is then *opened* with [`open_existential_addr`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#open_existential_addr), which gets a pointer to the instance stored (the `MyClass` instance).

Then, [`witness_method`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst#witness_method) is used in order to lookup the function to call for the protocol requirement `MyProtocol.testFuncA` for the `MyClass` instance. This will check the protocol witness table for `MyClass`'s conformance, which is listed at the bottom of the generated SIL:

```
sil_witness_table hidden MyClass: MyProtocol module main {
  method #MyProtocol.testFuncA!1: <Self where Self : MyProtocol> (Self) -> () -> () : @protocol witness for main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> () in conformance main.MyClass : main.MyProtocol in main // protocol witness for MyProtocol.testFuncA() in conformance MyClass
}
```

This lists the function `@protocol witness for main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> ()`. We can check the implementation of this function:

```
// protocol witness for MyProtocol.testFuncA() in conformance MyClass
sil private [transparent] [thunk] @protocol witness for main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> () in conformance main.MyClass : main.MyProtocol in main : $@convention(witness_method) (@in_guaranteed MyClass) -> () {
// %0                                             // user: %2
bb0(%0 : $*MyClass):
  %1 = alloc_stack $MyClass                       // users: %7, %6, %4, %2
  copy_addr %0 to [initialization] %1 : $*MyClass // id: %2

  // Get a reference to the extension method and call it.
  // function_ref MyProtocol.testFuncA()
  %3 = function_ref @(extension in main):main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> () : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> () // user: %4
  %4 = apply %3<MyClass>(%1) : $@convention(method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> ()


  %5 = tuple ()                                   // user: %8
  destroy_addr %1 : $*MyClass                     // id: %6
  dealloc_stack %1 : $*MyClass                    // id: %7
  return %5 : $()                                 // id: %8
} // end sil function 'protocol witness for main.MyProtocol.testFuncA() -> () in conformance main.MyClass : main.MyProtocol in main'
```

and sure enough, its getting a `function_ref` to the extension method, and calling that function.

The looked-up witness function is then called after the `witness_method` lookup with the line:

```
  %11 = apply %10<@opened("F199B87A-06BA-11E8-A29C-DCA9047B1400") MyProtocol>(%9) : $@convention(witness_method) <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : MyProtocol> (@in_guaranteed τ_0_0) -> () // type-defs: %9
```

So, we can conclude that dynamic protocol dispatch is used here, based on the use of `witness_method`.

We just breezed though quite a lot of technical details here; feel free to work through the SIL line-by-line, using [the documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst) to find out what each instruction does. I'm happy to clarify anything you may be unsure about.

Comment: You are awesome! This is exactly what i want to know! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Maize Happy to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

It's tricky question just because we're talking about details of compiler implementation and they can be changed with every new version of Swift (so any knowledge may become obsolete quite fast).

Speaking of Swift 3, I've encountered article some time ago: https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/12/swift-method-dispatch/. It actually tells us that

> Swift has two locations where a method can be declared: inside the
>   initial declaration of a type, and in an extension. Depending on the
>   type of declaration, this will change how dispatch is performed.
>
> ```
> class MyClass {
>     func mainMethod() {} }
>
> extension MyClass {
>     func extensionMethod() {} }
> ```
>
> In the example above, mainMethod will use table dispatch, and
>   extensionMethod will use direct dispatch

It also contains table:
[image]

According to this table methods declared in protocol extensions (so called default implementations) are always *dispatched directly*.

I can't tell for sure, but I believe that same behavior may occur in Swift 4.

Comment: I have read this article too. I believe in my example, `testFuncA` belongs **Initial Declaration** case, so it should be table dispatch. And my question it's what dose "table dispatch" mean? It's use MyClass's v-table, or existential container' PWT?

Comment: As far as I understand, it should use PWT. But I'd go with LLDB to check

Comment: You mean use PWT without existential container? I thought the PWT always comes with the existential container╮(╯_╰)╭
By the way, how do you check your guess?

Answer (score -1):

class MyClass compares your protocol MyProtocol. So your object knows about protocol implementation. Thats all. Or I don't understood the question?

Comment: So you meaning it's direct dispatch?