# How does one "override" a function from a Swift protocol extension in another extension?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols

The app in question here starts with a class being injected directly from the `AppDelegate` with its `UIWindow`:

```
public var window: UIWindow? {
    get { return nil }
    set {
        guard _window == nil else { return }
        _window = newValue
        _window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        start()
    }
}
```

The above code resides in a Cocoapod, and the idea with the `start()` function is that it gets a bespoke implementation in whatever code/app is implementing said Cocoapod:

```
extension TheStartingClass {
    func start () {
        // do whatever needs doing...
    }
}
```

`"TheStartingClass"` is a class that has a `TheStartingClassProtocol`, both of which are in the Cocoapod. Whether:

1. the start function is in the protocol and the class; or
2. the start function is in the protocol and the protocol extension; or
3. the start function is only in the protocol extension,

when re-implemented in `extension TheStartingClass` outside the Cocoapod, the re-implementation is ignored, I'm guessing because of something to do with [the way protocols dispatch methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703205/swift-protocol-extension-method-is-called-instead-of-method-implemented-in-subcl).

How can I change this code so that `func start ()` in `extension TheStartingClass` is actually called?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try subclassing `TheStartingClass`

Comment: @LeoDabus exactly right. I got caught up with this once.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid subclassing @LeoDabus because of its various evils. Is there no other way?

Comment: Let me rephrase that more honestly: "I am not going to subclass anything, because..."

Comment: Instead of a subclass, I changed the code so it doesn't need the subclass. Thanks all