# Why do I have to implement append<S: Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S) in my custom RangeReplaceableCollection

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift4.1

I am currently trying to update a custom collection type to Swift 4.1.
However, when I adhere to the documentation and implement all requirements for `Collection` and `RangeReplaceableCollection`, Xcode is still complaining that my type does not conform to `RangeReplaceableCollection`.

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/a7a8b2b70c8eff9efec2b4e6a94338f8) an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the problem (generously provided by Hamish, thank you for that :)

```
class Foo<Element : AnyObject> {
  required init() {}
  private var base: [Element] = []
}

extension Foo : Collection {
  typealias Index = Int

  var startIndex: Index {
    return base.startIndex
  }

  var endIndex: Index {
    return base.endIndex
  }

  func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
    return base.index(after: i)
  }

  subscript(index: Index) -> Element {
    return base[index]
  }
}

extension Foo : RangeReplaceableCollection {
  func replaceSubrange<C : Collection>(
    _ subrange: Range<Index>, with newElements: C
  ) where Element == C.Element {}
}
```

[According to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection), the code should compile:

> To add RangeReplaceableCollection conformance to your custom
>   collection, add an empty initializer and the replaceSubrange(_:with:)
>   method to your custom type. RangeReplaceableCollection provides
>   default implementations of all its other methods using this
>   initializer and method.

Unfortunately though, it doesn't. Instead, Xcode emits the following error message:

```
// error: type 'Foo<Element>' does not conform to protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollection'
// extension Foo : RangeReplaceableCollection {
// ^
//   Swift.RangeReplaceableCollection:5:26: note: candidate has non-matching type '<Self, S> (contentsOf: S) -> ()' [with SubSequence = Foo<Element>.SubSequence]
//   public mutating func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S : Sequence, Self.Element == S.Element
//                        ^
//   Swift.RangeReplaceableCollection:9:26: note: protocol requires function 'append(contentsOf:)' with type '<S> (contentsOf: S) -> ()'; do you want to add a stub?
//   public mutating func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S : Sequence, Self.Element == S.Element
//
```

To make sure it's not an error in the documentation, I checked [the source code of Swift 4.1](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/swift-4.1-RELEASE) and found the default implementation of `func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S: Sequence, Element == S.Element` in RangeReplaceableCollection.swift, lines 442-452:

```
@_inlineable
public mutating func append<S : Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S) where S.Element == Element {
  let approximateCapacity = self.count + numericCast(newElements.underestimatedCount)
  self.reserveCapacity(approximateCapacity)
  for element in newElements {
    append(element)
  }
}
```

---

#### Question:

- Why does Xcode ask for an implementation of this function although a default implementation is provided?
- How do I get my code to compile?

Comment: Your link to the project does not work. Generally all relevant code must be included in the question itself (as offsite resources might become unavailable, making the question useless for future readers).

Comment: You need to implement the requirement `mutating func replaceSubrange<C>(_ subrange: Range<Self.Index>, with newElements: C) where C : Collection, Self.Element == C.Element` (not the generic variant over `RangeExpression`). Could you please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the link. I am currently trying to implement a minimal, complete and verifiable example and will update the question accordingly. Thanks :)

Comment: Here's an mcve for you: https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/a7a8b2b70c8eff9efec2b4e6a94338f8. Looks like a bug to me; if you uncomment the `required init<S : Sequence>` and `func append<S : Sequence>` it compiles (it also compiles if you mark the class as `final` or are in Swift 4.0.3). Looks like the generic placeholder in the requirement is the problem. By the looks of the error message I think this could actually be related to the change discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49792626/2976878.... I'll file a bug when I get a moment.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that's kind of you. Meanwhile, I had also created an mcve, just without the inlined error message: https://gist.github.com/JanNash/ce344a40747b9fc38b83c14fa86247c2
// I'll try to salvage the question.

Comment: Bug filed: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7429

Comment: Great! Do you think it makes sense trying to improve the question, or should we rather vote to close/delete?

Comment: @JanNash That's up to you; if you update it with an mcve, it could be a useful Q&A to point people having the same issue to.

Comment: Agreed, done, open for improvement suggestions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why does Xcode ask for an implementation of this function although a default implementation is provided?

This is due to a bug in the TypeChecker, introduced in Swift 4.1:
[[SR-7429]: Cannot conform a non-final class to a protocol with a defaulted requirement with a generic placeholder constrained to an associated type](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7429)

#### How do I get my code to compile?

Until the bug is fixed, there's currently three ways to get it to compile.

- Implement these two functions:

  - `required init<S : Sequence>(_ elements: S) where Element == S.Element {}`
  - `func append<S : Sequence>(contentsOf newElements: S) where Element == S.Element`
- Mark the class as `final`.
- Implement the collection type as a `struct`. For this, the `required init() {}` must be removed.