# Swift: dynamic dispatch with protocol and subclass

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, dynamic-dispatch

Please consider the following Swift 5 code:

```
protocol P: class {
    func call_foo()
    func foo()
    func call_bar()
    func bar()
}

extension P {
    func call_foo() { foo() }
    func foo() { print("P.foo") }
    func call_bar() { bar() }
    func bar() { print("P.bar") }
}

class C1: P {
    func foo() { print("C1.foo") }
}

class C2: C1 {
    func bar() { print("C2.bar") }
}

let c = C2()
c.call_foo()    //  C1.foo
c.foo()         //  C1.foo
c.call_bar()    //  P.bar
c.bar()         //  C2.bar
```

If the `foo()` call in `P.call_foo()` gets dynamically dispatched to `C1.foo()`, then why the `bar()` call in `P.call_bar()` does not get dynamically dispatched to `C2.bar()`?

The only difference is that `foo()` is overridden directly in the class that conforms to `P`, and `bar()` is only overridden in a subclass. Why does that make a difference?

Given that `bar()` is a protocol requirement, shouldn't all calls to it always get dynamically dispatched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your extension:

```
extension P {
    func call_foo() { foo() }
    func foo() { print("P.foo") }
    func call_bar() { bar() }
    func bar() { print("P.bar") }
}
```

`C2` does not exist, `P` is a protocol, and methods are dispatched statically, and although `bar()` is a requirements of `P`, it is not implemented by `C1` which has the conformance to `P` so:

```
let c1: some P = C1()
c1.call_foo()    //  C1.foo
c1.foo()         //  C1.foo
c1.call_bar()    //  P.bar
c1.bar()         //  P.bar
```

and that is normal, and interestingly you have:

```
let someP: some P = C2()
someP.call_foo()    //  C1.foo
someP.foo()         //  C1.foo
someP.call_bar()    //  P.bar
someP.bar()         //  P.bar
```

Meaning that if you only have a reference to `some P`, the subclass `C2` of `C1` behaves exactly as it's superclass: `call_bar()` calls `P.bar()` because `C1` does not implement `bar()`

now let's look at what happens if you implement `bar()` in `C1`:

```
class C1: P {
    func foo() { print("C1.foo") }
    func bar() { print("C1.bar") }
}

class C2: C1 {
    override func bar() { print("C2.bar") }
}
```

If we use a reference to `C1` using `some P`:

```
let c1: some P = C1()
c1.call_foo()    //  C1.foo
c1.foo()         //  C1.foo
c1.call_bar()    //  C1.bar
c1.bar()         //  C1.bar
```

now in `call_bar()` the compiler *knows* it has to use `C1.bar()` so with a reference to `C2` using `some P`:

```
let someP: some P = C2()
someP.call_foo()    //  C1.foo
someP.foo()         //  C1.foo
someP.call_bar()    //  C2.bar
someP.bar()         //  C2.bar
```

The subclass `C2` still behaves the same way as it's superclass `C1` and it's implementation of `bar()` get's called. (And I find it somewhat [reassuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) when sublasses behave as their parent).

now let's check the original snippet :

```
let c = C2()
c.call_foo()    //  C1.foo
c.foo()         //  C1.foo
c.call_bar()    //  C2.bar
c.bar()         //  C2.bar
```

it work's !

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that there's only a single witness table for `C1`'s conformance to P (as opposed to also having a separate one for each subclass of `C1`), shared between all instances of `C1` or any of its subclasses?

Comment: yes, for more details see @Hamish answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44706021/1425697

Comment: Ok, thanks. This explains the behavior I'm seeing, though I still don't understand the rationale behind it. Thanks for the link, I'll keep reading.