# Swift Protocol Extension unexpected behavior

Tags: swift, protocols, default-value

I am having trouble understanding why `t` and `tt` are treated differently. Obviously it has to due with what is specified directly in protocol A, but what is the logic here for this difference?

```
protocol A {
    var t : Int {get}
} 
extension A {
    var t : Int {
        return 1
    }
    var tt : Int {
        return 1
    }
}
struct B : A {
    var t = 2
    var tt = 2
}
let a:A = B()
print(a.t, a.tt) //"2 1"
let b:B = B()
print(b.t, b.tt) //"2 2"
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44703205/1187415 to me, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/67366719/1187415.

Comment: That did answer my question. Thanks